# FreeBSD Gnu Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu, freebsd

I want to compile about 100 and 100 .h .cpp files.

How can I create GNU Makefile, to compile under FreeBSD.

I mean I do not know how to make dependencies, lib, linker.

You must compile and .cpp .c .o .h

And I've never used the GNU Makefile.

Comment: If it's just about compiling `for a in *.cpp;do g++ -c $a;done` ;-). But I guess that's not what you're looking for. Be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a makefile that will compile **every** cpp file in the current directory into `program`. It is GNU make specific. Note that on FreeBSD, `make` is not GNU make! You need to install and run gmake.

```
CPPFLAGS := # flags for preprocessing: -D -I etc.
CXXFLAGS := -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -Wformat=2
LDFLAGS  := # linker options, like -L/usr/local/boost/lib
LDLIBS   := # libraries to link to, e.g. -lboost_system

SOURCES := $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

all: program # by convention, the first (default) target is called "all"

program: $(OBJECTS)
        $(LINK.o) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

clean:
        rm -f $(OBJECTS) program
```

GNU make has built-in rules to build a .o from a .cpp; we just have to supply some parameters to that rule (CPPFLAGS, CXXFLAGS).

It also know how to make `program` from a single `program.o`. This is not useful in our case, because there are multiple .o files. Therefore we must explicitly tell make that `program` depends on the object files, and a recipe to produce it.

If you have foo.cpp and bar.cpp in the current directory, `SOURCES` will have the value `foo.cpp bar.cpp` and `OBJECTS` will be `foo.o bar.o` . When you invoke `make` without an explicit target, it tries to build the first target it sees (all). `all` depends on `program`, so make tries to build `program`. Make sees that `program` needs `foo.o` and `bar.o` but they don't exist. Luckily, make sees that there's a `foo.cpp` and it knows how to create `foo.o` from it; same with `bar.o` . After it compiles the C++ files to produce the object files, it can go ahead and link them to produce `program`